# How do I appreciate a subject matter expert's expertise?

Tags: creative-writing, email, getting-started

Situation -A subject matter expert is helping me with something that, well, matters. (to me)

I want to send a quick one liner thank you and let her know that I fully appreciate the time that she would be spending on this AND that I respect and am glad about the fact that she has the domain knowledge that I don't.

What would be the correct version of -

*I appreciate the time you will spend on this and the fact that you have the necessary expertise*

(Please help retag this question appropriately. I browsed through the available tags but am not sure if I chose the most appropriate ones.)

Comment: If you are really that thankful to her, maybe a *quick one liner* just isn't enough.

Comment: @John - its at the start of the project and I have just been introduced. so i would rather keep it to a line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Thank you so much for generously sharing your time and expertise." With additional superlatives and the word "appreciate" as needed.

Answer (score 5):

"This project could not be completed without your specific expertise and generous support.  Please know you have my deepest thanks."

You may want to add some details that characterize your interactions so that the message is a little more personal.  The phrase 'specific expertise' is a little vague.

Did she provide you with archived recordings of mission data?  Werer there particular anecdotes that stuck in your mind?  Was her field of research perfectly suited to your needs?  Did she come prepared with files for you to examine at your lesiure?  Did she suggest additional resources that increased your knowledge of the subject?

These are just a few examples that I would mention (if they occurred) so that the recipient knew I was not just sending a stock greeting, but a genuine thank you- specifically thought out and intended for her.

Finally, it doesn't hurt to mention that you will include a 'sepcial thanks' in your final product in her name.

Comment: +1 for the mention of "special thanks in the final product." Public acknowledgment goes a long way.

Comment: +1 but this thanks is in advance (..time that she *would* be spending on this..) so your answer is a little bit off.

Comment: One can do both.